# 1000s of Questions unanswered for months

Tags: discussion

I see that there are many many questions here that do not have a single answer and the questions are posted months ago, many in 2011 and quite a few in 2010.

What's wrong? Why aren't these questions answered until now?

I personally answered a lot of those questions yesterday, they are not difficult or strange or anything like that.

What's wrong?

Why will users come back if they are not getting answers to their questions at all?

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem with a site like ours where the there are several factors that contribute to this:

1. Our remit is fairly broad - all web applications. No one person can be expert in them all so there will be questions people can't answer.
2. Our direct traffic is relatively low - even compared to some of the other smaller sites. This means that there is more chance that no one will see a question once it drops off the home page unless they go looking.
3. The majority of our users are more likely to be unregistered - after finding the site via a Google search or register to post a single question or answer and then don't return for a long time afterwards. Again I think that this is due to the nature of the problems people face.

So it's good that you are finding this unanswered questions and providing answers - it all helps.

If you have any ideas for increasing participation please post them here on meta.

Comment: *Our direct traffic is low, our overall is pretty high

Comment: @phwd - That's what I meant, we have more "drive by" users.